# How to impute missing values with median value

Tags: hive, apache-pig, bigdata, median, missing-data

I need to impute missing values with the median value using Apache Pig.

Is there an efficient way to do that?

For R, I remember using the following steps:

```
a <- c(1, 2, NA, 3)
a[is.na(a)] <- median(a, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But I need an efficient solution using Apache Pig.

Comment: How is your data structured? Do you want to use the median of the column or of the row?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to give 'read the instructions' answers, but you really need to know how Pig handles Null values, because it's quite different from R.

This is the Pig Manual page on nulls:  [Pig Manual Nulls](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#nulls)

That being said, you can use the DataFu library from LinkedIn to perform a Median calculation on a **SORTED ORDER** bag.

```
REGISTER datafu-1.2.0.jar
DEFINE MEDIAN datafu.pig.stats.Median();

--input data: 3,5,4,1,2
input = LOAD 'input' AS (val:int);

grouped = GROUP input ALL;

medians = FOREACH grouped {
  sorted = ORDER input BY val;
  GENERATE MEDIAN(sorted.val);
}
```

At this point, you need to go back and perform the replacement of the null with the new median (3, in the case above).

A common method for null replacement is:

```
data = FOREACH data GENERATE (val IS NOT NULL ? val : 0) as result;
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't really work in your case, because you're the value you're trying to substitute is different for each bag.

You could handle this in a few ways ... the easiest might be to simply add the median to the end of the bag, and then do a FOREACH GENERATE (val IS NOT NULL ? val : medianval).

Answer (score 0):

I created a UDF to do this. That worked out well.